# The method call is not allowed in the onclick tag of the form tag

Tags: javascript

What should I do?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function add(){
        var a = document.getElementById("n1").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("n2").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
    }
    </script>
    <form>
       <input type="text" id="n1">+
       <input type="text" id="n2">
       <input type="button" value="=" onclick="add();">
       <input type="text" id="result">
    </form>
```

"Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined"

Comment: What you posted works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2qnuar3z/

Comment: Your code works as expected. I'm voting to close this question as the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: so what's the problem? seems to work?

Comment: the problem is probably not in the code you posted but in some other code, do you have call `add` in any other `onclick`(or whatever `onX`) ? do you call it inside `<script></script>` ?

Comment: I did not get "result" because it overlapped with another script at the top. Conclusion solved